# JS : href in if statement

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am new to JS. So pardon my ignorance. I am trying to redirect my webpage to a different IP when a particular condition is satisfied and I am not able to achieve it using  with JS.

My code is:

```
<script>
    if( isMobile.iOS() ) 
        {
         <!--ignore-->
        }
    else if( isMobile.Android() ) 
        {
        text = "<a href="rtsp://a.b.c.d:1935/live/myStream1" id="player2"> Redirecting </a>";
        }
</script>
```

I used w3schools as reference!

P.S- I tried the exact same format with just alert('IOS')/ alert('Android') and it worked with the mobiles and tablets I have.

Thanks.

Comment: if you're trying to redirect, try setting `location.href = "rtsp://a.b.c.d:1935/live/myStream1"`;

Comment: Hi Bencripps, Yes I am trying to automatically redirect to this link which has a live streaming video. But, your suggestion did not seem to work as well.

Comment: In order to get this redirected automatically, I have included another script as follows:                                         <script type="text/javascript">
 function init(){
 var linkPage=document.getElementById('player2').href;
  window.location.href = linkPage;
 }
 onload=init;
</script>                                                                                              And that is why I wanted to specify the "id=player2" as in the code I posted initially.

Answer (score 0):

Like said in the comments, if you are trying to change the location of the application you should do:

```
location.href = "rtsp://a.b.c.d:1935/live/myStream1";
```

But if you are trying to insert an "a" tag into the screen you have to verify you quotes in the string.
In javascript it is a good practice to use single comma (') when writing a string, changing your code from this:

```
text = "<a href="rtsp://a.b.c.d:1935/live/myStream1" id="player2"> Redirecting </a>";
//     ↑ here                                                             and here ↑
```

to this:

```
text = '<a href="rtsp://a.b.c.d:1935/live/myStream1" id="player2"> Redirecting </a>';
//     ↑ here                                                             and here ↑
```

This is exactly because is common have cases like yours when we need to put html in a string in javascript and the attributes of the elements in html commonly have double quotes.

The error happens because when the interpreter reaches the second (") he thinks that you have entered your full string and the next text is a command in javascript to interpret, but is not and it crashes.

If you want to use double-quotes anyway you have to escape them with a backslash like this:

```
text = "<a href=\"rtsp://a.b.c.d:1935/live/myStream1\" id=\"player2\"> Redirecting </a>";
//              ↑ here                         here ↑     ↑ here   ↑ and here
```

*Please up vote this answer if it took your doubts.*

Comment: Hi wesleycoder, Thank you for the response. My code was working till before I tried to do separate actions for IOS/Android. I tried both examples you have specified. But, still do not get my livestream video. Any other suggestions ? As I said, I am not familiar with JS and have no idea.